# why the name `reduce` was adopted instead of `fold` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I did a search on this topic, but I do not know what keyword to search for so I post this question.

I wondered why the name `reduce` was chosen in javascript even though the name has been used, such as `fold` or `accumulate`, which is more traditional and meaningful(this is my personal opinion).

I've spoken about this topic with someone close to me (one of the people I know who has been dealing with Javascript for a long time and who has also worked with functional languages like Scheme, Racket, and Clojure). He cautiously speculated that this might be an effect of Python.

If you have any traditional context that I do not know, or someone you know about the background of this name, I would be very grateful if you could answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_in_various_languages, you can see that the most common names for this operation are `fold`, `reduce`, and `inject`. `reduce` is by no means an unusual name. In particular, `reduce` is used in Perl (which JavaScript copied many features from), and Perl probably got it from Lisp (like many other features). The earliest reference I can find is [`REDUCE` in Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_reduce.htm) (which was developed in the 1980s and standardized in 1994).